# Flatten a managed metadata hierarchy for an MVC dropdown list using CSOM

Tags: csom, asp.net, term-store, .net

I currently have a structure that has the following structure

Offices --> which is a Term

- > ```
  > Region 1
  >           Area 1
  >             Town 1
  >             Town 2
  >          Area 2
  >             Town 1
  > Region 2
  >           Area 1
  >             Town 1
  > ```

and so on

What I am aiming to do is to flatten out this hierarchy using CSOM so I can display it in a drop down list for an MVC app I am using.

My starting point was

```
    public TermCollection Offices()
    {
                var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
                var termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore();
                var parentTermId = Guid.Parse("0d874cd3-da81-460a-8f49-a2286601654b");
                var parentTerm = termStore.GetTerm(parentTermId);
                officeTerms = parentTerm.Terms;
                clientContext.Load(officeTerms);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

I then return the officeTerms collection and wrap it in a selectList

This only loads the terms at the Region level. After a bit of digging it seemed that I need to recursively load any terms that have children so I added 
LoadTerms(officeTerms) after ExecuteQuery above to give me

```
        public TermCollection Offices()
        {
            var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
            var termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore();
            var parentTermId = Guid.Parse("0d874cd3-da81-460a-8f49-a2286601654b");
            var parentTerm = termStore.GetTerm(parentTermId);
            officeTerms = parentTerm.Terms;
            clientContext.Load(officeTerms);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            LoadTerms(officeTerms)
}
```

and this method

```
private void LoadTerms(TermCollection offices, ClientContext context)
        {
            TermCollection terms;
            foreach (var office in offices)
            {
                TermCollection termCollection = office.Terms;
                if (practice.TermsCount > 0)
                {
                    context.Load(termCollection, tc => tc.Include(t => t.TermsCount,t => t.Terms, t => t.Name));
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    LoadTerms(termCollection, context);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with this of that when I call LoadTerms the officeTerms collection is no longer referenced so I cannot include the children.

My question is how do I get the Offices method to load all children of all terms and return that to flatten the list.

Thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the design to make Offices as a TermSet instead of Term , you can use [TermSet.GetAllTerms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.termset.getallterms.aspx) which will give all terms inside a termset in flat hierarchy.

Or you could add an extra filter on the result returned by TermSet.GetAllTerms.

```
 private static void getTerms()
        {
            var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(ctx);
            var termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            TermGroup termGroup = termStore.Groups.GetByName("<groupName>");
            // Get the term set by Name
            TermSet termSet = termGroup.TermSets.GetByName("<termSetName>");
            TermCollection termColl = termSet.GetAllTerms();
            var allTerms=ctx.LoadQuery(termColl);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            //get only the terms inside another term 
            foreach (var term in allTerms.Where(t=> t.PathOfTerm.StartsWith("<parentTerm>;")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(term.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Quite new to Sharepoint but am not sure I can do that as Office is in a Termset called Locations which also contains other hierarchical terms such as Departments. I get the feeling this would break the design.

Comment: Updated my answer